# Get Vue component object (class) from component instance

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

**Question**

Given I am in component context, how do I get the *component object*? By *component object* I mean the object you get when you `import Component from 'Component.vue'`.

**Current progress**

Here's one possibility I found.

```js
const component = {
  methods: {
    getComponent: () => this,
    displayItem () {
      console.log('this.getComponent()', this.getComponent()) // undefined
      console.log('this', this) // component instance
      console.log('component', component) // what I need (component object)
    },
  },
}

export default component
```

The downside though is that it kills IDE support.

I also checked `this` manually.

**Ideal solution**

The approximation to syntax I'd like to see: `this.$component`.

**What's the point?**

1. Instantiate components via `:is="component"`.
2. Perform *instance of* check.

Comment: Inside the component's methods you can do `this`.

Comment: @Phiter Nope. That's component instance.

Comment: maybe `vm.$options._Ctor[0]` but i'm not sure what `[0]` is here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closer you got is [**`vm.$options`**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-options):

```js
Vue.component('some-comp', {
  template: '<p>{{ message }}</p>',
  props: {name: String},
  data() {
    return {
      message: 'Open the console!'
    }
  },
  computed: {
    example() {
      return this.message.toUpperCase();
    }
  },
  watch: {
    message() {
      console.log('watcher triggered');
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$options);
    console.dir(this.$options.__proto__);
  }
});
new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <some-comp :name="'Alice'"></some-comp>
</div>
```

But it seems what you want is `constructor`:

```js
Vue.component('aaa-aaa', {
  template: '<div>AAA component</div>'
})
Vue.component('bbb-bbb', {
  template: '<div>BBB component</div>'
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$refs.a1);
    console.log(this.$refs.a1.constructor);
    console.log(this.$refs.b1);
    console.log(this.$refs.b1.constructor);

    console.log('a1 a2', this.$refs.a1.constructor === this.$refs.a2.constructor)
    console.log('a1 b1', this.$refs.a1.constructor === this.$refs.b1.constructor)
    console.log('b1 b2', this.$refs.b1.constructor === this.$refs.b2.constructor)
    console.log('b2 a2', this.$refs.b2.constructor === this.$refs.a2.constructor)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <aaa-aaa ref="a1"></aaa-aaa>
  <aaa-aaa ref="a2"></aaa-aaa>

  <bbb-bbb ref="b1"></bbb-bbb>
  <bbb-bbb ref="b2"></bbb-bbb>
</div>
```

Comment: Added "What's the point" block to my question. Just checked your solution. Works for component istantiation via :is. Doesn't work for `instance of` check ($options are instantiated).

I wonder if vue stores the clean object even. It seems as if it's Object.assing-ed somewhere and gets lost.

Comment: Look closer, there's no class involved. Your code does `const component = {/* plain JS object here */}; export default component;`. At no point a class is created, just a plain object.

Comment: Pardon my french : 3. My choice of wording was to simplify explanation. You can loosely consider component used in template (this) to be an "instance". And component object (options) you can consider "class". And I basically want to figure if 2 "instances" belong to same "class".

Comment: `this.$options.__proto__ === component` gives false. So also not applicable for *instance of* check. I'm thinking to compare name `this.$options.name === 'component.name'` -> true. But this requires strict convention (always unique `name`), which is sub-optimal, as I'm building a public library.

Comment: Try `this.constructor`